# How to get rid of 'UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW' while deleting multiple Group Members from a Group

Tags: visual-workflow, batch, locking, scheduled-flow

I'm working on a scheduled flow which will delete all the Group Members present in a group after which I can add the required Group Members. But when the flow runs in scheduled mode it throws an error 'UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW' on delete element. Also, there's an interesting thing when I run this flow in debug mode, I don't get any errors and all the operations are performed perfectly. I would like to know why I don't get any errors while running it in Debug mode either in rollback mode or not.

I guess the reason for this error could be that the Parent object (i.e: Group) is getting locked while other child objects (i.e: GroupMembers) are being deleted at the same time. And, if I could run this in smaller batches I won't be getting this error, but this option is not feasible in Scheduled Flow.

I would really appreciate any help on this, feel free to get any other input from me. Thanks!
[image]